# When using NLog Mail target how do I get an email per log entry?

Tags: .net, nlog

When using the NLog mail target I get multiple log entries in a single email but I need an email per log entry.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Be default NLog would send a mail per log entry, as I doesn't buffered log entries.

But when using `async=true`, the `AsyncWrapper` or `BufferingWrapper`, log entries are bufferend. That is useful when you like to send a mail with the 10 latest log entries.